# Creating a responsive version of a complex function

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

I am working on a little project. I need to implement some kind of an algorithm which in most cases will use much of a CPU's resources and therefore take some time to execute and return. I want this method to be kind of responsive and notify of any progress. I might also want to do some other processes while doing these computations.

Consider this class that has the complex method

```
class Engine
{
    public int ComplexMethod(int arg)
    {
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
            {
                // some complex and time-consuming computations
            }

            // it would be nice to get notified on arriving this point for example
        }

        return result; 
    }
}
```

What is the best approach to this case?

EDIT: I should have mentioned that it is an app with UI (a WPF application).

Comment: Try [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: For parallelization, you can either use PLINQ or [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the outer loop, depending how the calculations look like. For asynchrony, wrap it in a `Task` and return a `Task<int>`, while accepting `IProgress<T>` for progress notifications.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Winforms, console, ...?

Comment: It is a WPF application. Added this important info

Comment: Initiate a new thread that updates the UI/Console as per requirement. Don't wait for this thread. Initiate every time you want to update progress. In case of complex long time thread prefer BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run the process in a new thread using `Task.Run`, and use the `IProgress<T>` interface to notify progress:

```
class Engine
{
    public int ComplexMethod(int arg, IProgress<double> progress)
    {
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
            {
                // some complex and time-consuming computations
            }

            progress.Report(i / 100000);
        }

        return result; 
    }
}

...

var progress = new Progress<double>(p => ShowProgress(p));
var result = await Task.Run(() => engine.ComplexMethod(arg, progress));
ShowResult(result);
```

If you have a UI (which is likely), the progression delegate will automatically be called on the UI thread, using `Control.Invoke` (Windows Forms) or `Dispatcher.Invoke` (WPF, WinRT, Silverlight), provided that the `Progress<T>` instance was created on the UI thread.

Note that `async/await` won't help (inside the method) if the computation is CPU-bound. However it can be used to make it easier to retrieve the result, as shown above. If for some reason you can't or don't want to use `await`, you can use `ContinueWith`, specifying `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` for the `scheduler` parameter.

Comment: This seems to be a good start. However, I cannot figure out how to resolve `result` value, which is probably going to be some data-model more complex than an integer.

Comment: @patryk, see my updated answer. You can retrieve the result directly from the task, using `await`

Comment: This is what I like to see - await used. And also you mention that it is possible to use the `await` calling the method, what I actually thought of at the first place. I am going to give it a try, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using .NET 4.5 (C# 5), you can use `TPL` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423(v=vs.110).aspx).

With not knowing your algorithm, all I can suggest is that you return a `Task<int>` instead of returning a `int`.  This will allow for the function to be ran easily in parallel with other tasks.

I would recommend the following:

```
public Task<int> ComplexMethodAsync(int arg)
{
  Task.Run(()=>ComplextMethod(arg));
}
```

Now, when you run this method, the `ComplexMethod(arg)` will be called on a separate thread from the `ThreadPool`.  Call it with:

```
await ComplextMethodAsync(xyz);
```

Check out [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) for more information.

Comment: This answer does not provide what the OP is asking - i.e., progress response.

Comment: Ah, I glazed over that part.